# How to send string data to socket connection via telnet or any other program?

Tags: string, sockets, connection, telnet

I am trying to send and receive string data to socket connection via telnet, but I am not able to type or see anything in the telnet window. I am able to connect to the server via telnet, but not able to send the string data.

Is there any other alternate method to send string data over socket connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telnet, unless it negotiates parameters to the contrary, does "remote echo" meaning that you won't see anything you type unless the server echos it back.

A lot of people use the term "Telnet" when really it is a raw socket connection that does no configuration negotiation upon connect.

If you're sending data from a file or source other than the keyboard (and even often when sending from the keyboard), you're better of using a program like `socket` or `nc` ([netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)) which don't attempt to do any processing of the data stream and so provide simple 8-bit clean connections.

In the case of both those problems, you can simply redirect stdin from a file or echo a string to them through a pipe.

Comment: Thanks Brian. how can i send string data via netcat. I need to send the below string (100,,,,42,CREDIT,,0074,074,SALE,)to the server and get back a response. Can i also see the response in netcat or do i have to login to the server to check for the response. Can you let me know if i can do it in nc.

Comment: `echo '100,,,,42,CREDIT,,0074,074,SALE,' | nc destip destport | cat -v` should do it.  `nc` and `socket` are just simple bidirectional pipes.  Whatever goes stdin gets sent to the server and whatever the server sends goes stdout.  You will see the response right on your terminal window only if the server sends it.  Beware that if the server sends binary data, it could affect your terminal (pipe into `cat -v` to be safe).  Note that `echo` will also send a LF at the end; add `-n` to stop that.  `nc` also closes the connection as soon as stdin gets EOF so be sure your server is okay with that.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I tried it and noticed the below error -C:\Users\adevasun>nc
Cmd line: echo '100,,,,42,CREDIT,,0074,074,SALE,,,4012000033330027,1604,,2724,74
2213,,,,*STORESTAN 742213,,,,,,,,,,*CVV2_125,,,5007407400221315031831823,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,03182015,085023,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,' | nc colstcd02.TEST.com 24901 | cat -v
echo: forward host lookup failed: h_errno 11001: HOST_NOT_FOUND      did i sent the syntax wroong?

Comment: Ah, well, DOS would require a different command syntax.  For one, `cat` isn't a standard command.  Also, the `echo` command doesn't want quotes (in puts them in the output) and may have issues with the asterisk and space characters.  Aside from that, is `nc` installed?  Can you use it to simply connect (without using the rest of the stuff on the line)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, i have NC installed and i am running it from cmd prompt on windows 7 machine. I am able to connect to the remotehost and port via NC. Is there any other alternate way to send the string request to the remote host via TCP?

Answer (score -1):

i have a example of a server that talks to with many telnet client.

You must use the class **DataInputStream** and **DataOutputStream** 
You must use **A Class** Implements Runnable for establish multiple sessions
You must use  a **ServerSocket** Class.

Good, this is the code of the main class called SocketServerExample:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import socketserverexample.ThreadServer;

 /**
 *
 * @author JuanLuisHiciano
 */
public class SocketServerExample {

public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

    ServerSocket mi_servicio = null;
    String linea_recibida;
    DataInputStream entrada = null;
    DataOutputStream salida = null;
    Socket socket_conectado = null;

    try {
        mi_servicio = new ServerSocket(2017);
    }
    catch (IOException excepcion) {
        System.out.println(excepcion);
    }
    try {

        int n=1;
        while(n<2){
            socket_conectado = mi_servicio.accept();
            System.out.println("Un cliente se a conectado "+socket_conectado.getPort());
            entrada= new DataInputStream(socket_conectado.getInputStream());
            String nombre = entrada.readUTF();
            // Se instancia una clase para atender al cliente y se lanza en
            // un hilo aparte.
            Runnable nuevoCliente = new ThreadServer(nombre, socket_conectado); //Input and Output data Channels 

            Thread hilo = new Thread(nuevoCliente);
            hilo.start();      

        }

        salida.writeUTF("Fin de la conexion....");


        salida.close();
        entrada.close();
        socket_conectado.close();
    }
    catch (IOException excepcion) {
        System.out.println(excepcion);
    }
}

}
```

ok,This run de Main Server with the UTP port (2017) and delivering sessions to other threads to receive new connections.

Good , below is the code of the class Called ThreadServer :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
/**
 *
 * @author JuanLuisHiciano
 */
 public class ThreadServer implements Runnable{

DataInputStream entrada;
DataOutputStream salida;
Socket socket_conectado = null;
String linea_recibida;
String cliente;

 ThreadServer(String cliente,Socket socket) {
    socket_conectado = socket;
    this.cliente=cliente;

}





@Override
public void run() {
    int n=0;
   while(n<3){
       try {
            salida = new DataOutputStream(socket_conectado.getOutputStream());
            entrada = new DataInputStream(socket_conectado.getInputStream());
            //System.out.println("Confirmando Conexion al cliente .....");
            salida.writeUTF("Conexion Exitosa\n");
            salida.writeUTF("Puede compartir un mensaje : ");
            //recepcion de mensaje
            linea_recibida = entrada.readUTF();
            System.out.println(cliente+" dice: "+linea_recibida); 
            System.out.println(socket_conectado.getPort());
            n++;
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(ThreadServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }


   }
}

}
```

With this code you can talk to each of the clients connecting.

Goodbye Saludos de Republica Dominicana

I hope you serve something this code.

Comment: I forgot to say that to connect via telnet must first enable telnet tool and use the telnet command < Telnet 'ip'  'socket'  >

Comment: You can `edit` your answer via the link above this comment section, in order to include any missing/changed information.

Comment: Additionally, this is a rather old, general question (without a specified programming language associated with it) that you are answering in a very specific way. Furthermore, your solution contains unnecessary code and non-english comments that might confuse.

Comment: its true , i dont understand well , i am new in StackOverflow

Comment: Carsten, they're comments, you don't really need to understand them.

You're better off understanding the code.